# Write and read ratings from firestore in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to have users submit star ratings and then have them stored under a collection within their document. I have the functions written which should do these things, getRatingsSubcollection, addTransactionRating, but I can't figure out how to place them in the structure so that they run for each user-submitted rating.

```
struct Rating: View {
    @State var userCurrentRating: CGFloat = 0.0
    var schools = ["North Avenue", "West Village", "Brittain"]
    @State private var location = "West Village"
    @State private var isUserRatingCurrent = true
    @State private var currentRating: CGFloat = 0.0
    var db: Firestore!
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 16) {
                    Divider()
                    Text("Choose a dining location:")
                        .bold()
                    Picker("Choose a dining location:", selection: $location) {
                        ForEach(schools, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0)
                        }
                    }
                    Text("Current Rating, \(currentRating)")
                        .bold()
                    if self.isUserRatingCurrent {
                        VStack {
                            RatingsViewCurrent(onDidRateCurrent: self.userDidRateCurrent, ratingCurrent: self.$userCurrentRating)
                                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                        }
                    } else {
                        VStack {
                            RatingsViewCurrent(ratingCurrent: self.$currentRating)
                                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                            if userCurrentRating == 0.0 {
                                Button("Rate") {
                                    self.isUserRatingCurrent = false
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Add a Rating")
        }
    }
    
    func userDidRateCurrent(_ ratingCurrent: Int) {            print("ratingcurrent \(ratingCurrent)")
        
    }
    // [START restaurant_struct]
    struct diningLocation {
        
        let location: String
        let currentRating: Float
        let usualRating: Float
        let totalRatings: Float
        
        init(location: String, currentRating: Float, usualRating: Float, totalRatings: Float) {
            self.location = location
            self.currentRating = currentRating
            self.usualRating = usualRating
            self.totalRatings = totalRatings
        }
        
    }
    
    let WestVillage = diningLocation(location: "West Village", currentRating: 4.65, usualRating: 2.9, totalRatings: 45.0)
    // [END restaurant_struct]
    
    struct Rating {
        let rating: Float
    }
    
    func getRatingsSubcollection() {
        // [START get_ratings_subcollection]
        db.collection("RatingInformation")
            .document("West Village")
            .collection("ratings")
            .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                
                // ...
            }
        // [END get_ratings_subcollection]
    }
    
    // [START add_rating_transaction]
    func addRatingTransaction(restaurantRef: DocumentReference, ratingCurrent: Float) {
        let ratingRef: DocumentReference = restaurantRef.collection("ratings").document()
        
        db.runTransaction({ (transaction, errorPointer) -> Any? in
            do {
                let restaurantDocument = try transaction.getDocument(restaurantRef).data()
                guard var restaurantData = restaurantDocument else { return nil }
                
                // Compute new number of ratings
                let totalRatings = restaurantData["totalRatings"] as! Int
                let newNumRatings = totalRatings + 1
                
                // Compute new average rating
                let usualRating = restaurantData["usualRating"] as! Float
                let oldRatingTotal = usualRating * Float(totalRatings)
                let newAvgRating = (oldRatingTotal + ratingCurrent) / Float(newNumRatings)
                
                // Set new restaurant info
                restaurantData["totalRatings"] = newNumRatings
                restaurantData["usualRating"] = newAvgRating
                
                // Commit to Firestore
                transaction.setData(restaurantData, forDocument: restaurantRef)
                transaction.setData(["rating": ratingCurrent], forDocument: ratingRef)
            } catch {
                // Error getting restaurant data
                // ...
            }
            
            return nil
        }) { (object, err) in
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```